# PHP script finishes when you start it manually, but not when its started via cronjob

Tags: php, cron

I have a PHP script running perfectly when I start the script via manually via browser. But when it runs via cronjob it starts but it doesn't run until the end of the script.

The cronjob and the script execution definitely starts (I've tested this already), but as I said: It doesn't run until the end of the script when the script is started via cronjob.

The script has already a "set_time_limit(0)" and I also tried "ignore_user_abort(TRUE)" but it doesn't help at all.

Thanks a lot in advance for every support to solve this problem.

Jennifer

Comment: Have you looked at the process with `strace` or the equivalent to see what it's doing?  Is it hung, or looping, or what?

Comment: without seeing the script, i would all just be guess work.

Comment: setting it to never time out, will not help it stop, it will do the opposite.

Comment: *"But when it runs via cronjob it starts but it doesn't run until the end of the script."* after edit, there are three 'it' which seem to be referring to diffirent things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you executing your php file using php or wget? It's different if you use php, because it takes a different configuration, and that configuration could be setting a low memory limit, so your script runs out of memory and stops/fails.

Actually, using directly php instead of wget, you could specify your own php.ini file to override some configuration options, using the -c option when calling your php. There you should increase your memory limit, execution time limit and so on.

Read the following link to see all the options you can use by choosing to use /bin/php (or whatever the path to your php) instead of wget: [PHP Arguments](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/php/)

Answer (score 1):

A script *always* finishes at some point. Have you tried putting a load of `echo(__LINE__)` in to see how far it's getting?

Comment: well, don't they finish when the computer powers down? :D Obviously some scripts are perpetual, but if a script is failing (as above) then it is ending

Comment: Sorry, my description was not correct: What I was trying to say was the PHP script doesn't run until the end of the script, when its started via cronjob. But when I start it manually it runs until the end of the PHP scipt.

Answer (score 0):

Check the user/group you run and invoke your php cron job and see if it satisfies the path environment variable. This could be a current working directory path issue. Sometimes in windows, you have to set the path to include the install path as well as your cron job path in the environment variable.